# php undefined variable - not sure if is to do with the sql-query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

what is wrong with query?

```
$sql="select * from cars where make LIKE '%$term%' AND town LIKE '$town' AND colour LIKE '$colour' AND Reg LIKE '$Reg' AND price > $price AND miles > $miles LIMIT $offset";

echo "<br>";



if (isset($_session['term']))$_session['term']="%";



echo "<br>";


$term=mysql_query($sql,$odbc) or die("Can not run query");

if(mysql_num_rows($term)==0)
{
    echo "no records returned";
}
else
{
    $recCount=mysql_num_rows($term);



    echo"<table>";
        echo"<tr >";
            echo"<td width=130 valign=top> <h4>Search Return:</h4></td>"; 
            echo"<td valign=top>$recCount</td>" ; 
            echo"<td width=150 valign=top> records are found.</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
    echo"</table>";
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Your likes need wildcard characters...

Comment: @SoulTrain  I was just about to say that

Comment: @SoulTrain - just added wildcard to all LIKE  except to price and miles as I thought not needed but no luck. same error: Undefined variable. Can not run query.

Comment: First try the query with just "SELECT * FROM cars" and see if that works. If not, put a "die" on your connection string. If you have the connection properly made, but the query doesn't work, then try the query in a MySQL tool like Workbench and see if you get syntax feedback.  I think your syntax is fine (once you add the wildcards) but you haven't shown us what your $offset contains. Also, if this is in production, you need to use mysql_real_escape_string liberally.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the query should be more like :

```
SELECT * 
FROM cars 
WHERE make LIKE '%".$term."%' 
AND town LIKE '%".$town."%' 
AND colour LIKE '%".$colour."%' 
AND Reg LIKE '%".$Reg."%' 
AND price > ".$price." 
AND miles > ".$miles." 
LIMIT ".$offset;
```

although you may want to look into [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Thanks . Nearly there , the only error I'm having is to do with  great than >. error:  syntax error, unexpected '>'